# File downloads intermittently failing?

Tags: java

I've inherited a java application that is used to transfer files.  Starting 3 months ago, it's been the case that when users attempt to download a file (they select the file from a drop down list and submit the form) the Open/Save dialog will open, but if they select Open, the file fails to download, and if they select Save, the Save As dialog fails to open.

The issue occurs intermittently, but it affects approximately 10% of all download attempts.  Below is the code used to perform the download, does there appear to be anything wrong with it?   I have been able to replicate by waiting 4-5 seconds after the Open/Save dialog box opens before selecting either Open or Save.

```
String fileName=downloadForm.getFileName();
String filePath=downloadForm.getDirPath()+File.separator;
File dPath=new File(filePath);
File f=new File(dPath,downloadForm.getFileName());
FileInputStream inStream=new FileInputStream(f);     
int size=new Long(f.length()).intValue();

response.setContentLength(size);
response.setContentType("application/x-file-download");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+ fileName);
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + MAX_AGE_IN_SECONDS);
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
CopyUtils.copy(inStream,outStream); // Copies input stream to output stream.
inStream.close();
outStream.flush();
```

Thanks,

Nathan